# how to change wordpress url structure

Tags: php, wordpress

in wordpress i want to set GET/POST variable as a url structure like this:

```
company.com/companies?name=xyz
```

to

```
compnay.com/companies/xyz
```

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can go to settings > permalink and select the one you want. You can use different tags such as %category% or fix words such as companies/%title%